# Etymological connection calx-calcaneum, callis, callum

Tags: etymology, romance-languages

***Calx-calcaneum*** (heel) has resulted in many [parallel and similar words across Romance](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/calcaneum#Descendants): *călcâi* in Romanian,  *cãlcãnju* in Aromanian, *calcagno* in Italian, Galician *calcañar/calcaño* etc.

***Callis*** (rough track, path of animal herd, then all kind of path or road) gave Romanian *cale*, meaning “way” (also, like in English *way* and French *voie*, “method”, “means”), “path” (also in computing), and “avenue”,  which has parallels in both Eastern (Aromanian *cali/cale* (road) and maybe [Dalmatian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cal#Dalmatian) *cal* (road, street)) and Western Romance ([calle](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/calle)). From Romanian *cale* derive *a călători* (to travel), *călător* (traveler, n.m.) and *călătorie* (travel, n.f.). —Latin *calator*, *calātōrius* - meaning personal attendant, servant of a priest, but [also “footman”](https://latin-dictionary.net/definition/7441/calator-calatoris) is not related, but is just based on *calō* (announce, proclaim; to summon, convoke), although the semantic closeness in Latin between  *calator* as “servant”, “footman” and *cālō -onis* (military servant), and also *cālō -ōnis* (military wooden shoe: Calones calcei ex ligno facti -  Paul-Festus 40, 25 L) is somewhat intriguing.—

***Callum*** – means hardened or thick substance, namely skin of animals (hide) or skin and flesh of plants; ***also the hard covering of soil***, also a ***callus, induration***.

Because my native language is Romanian and I have always felt that the verb *a călca* (tread, step, trample on) is connected to the noun *cale* (path, road) — and that also *a călca* > *călcătură*, n.f., “footprint, step”—, I have tried to look into a possible etymological relation between their roots. I was expecting something like the relation between *călca* (tread) and *călcâi* (heel): the latter is based on *calx > calcaneum*, and the former on *calcō < calx*. As mentioned above, *cale* comes from *callis* = road, path.

Looking for possible connections between these semantic areas I have found that *callis* was often connected with *callum*, given that the latter is also naming ***the hardened surface of soil*** ([Charlton T. Lewis, Charles Short, A Latin Dictionary](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text.jsp?doc=callum&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)
) - the ***trodden earth*** – *terra trita*, which is the very definition of *callis* as “path trodden by animals”. This is contradicted by some dictionaries (Ernout-Meillet, Walde-Hoffmann) but encouragingly accepted by others (M. de Vaan).

Ernout-Meillet, *Dictionnaire étymologique de la langue latine*:

[image]

[image]

*Etymological Dictionary of Latin and the Other Italic Languages* by M. de Vaan:

[image]

[image]

To me the probability of the *callis-callum* connection seems increased by the possible connection of each of them to *calx*.

A semantic relation between *cale*=”path” and the idea of “being repeatedly trodden” (tread=călca, trodden=călcat, footstep=călcătură) is often present in Romanian. A common expression is *cale bătută*, “well-trodden path”,  literally “beaten path”, which seems close to the original meaning of the root, just like in the expression *a bate cale lungă* (literally “to beat a long way”, meaning “to walk a long way”), or *a bate calea degeaba* (literally: "to *beat* the road in vain" - that is: to have walked a long way for nothing) where “to beat” is the natural, almost obligatory way of saying “to walk” (although in other cases "to beat" cannot be used instead of "to walk"), as if here *cale* required the violent aspect of “treading” (*a călca*=to tread, *călcat*=trodden) to be emphasized (an aspect which is essential to the relation *calx > calcō*; *calx* being a part of the foot used for 'kicking' (*Aduorsus stimulum calces*: "kicking against the pricks", *Oxford Latin Dictionary* - also [here](https://www.mqdq.it/texts/TER%7Cphor%7C001)), cf. Romanian *călcare/încălcare*=”violation”, Italian *calcio*=”kick”.

The verb “to beat” (*a bate/batere*), commonly used to express this aspect of being “well-trodden”, led to the word *bătătură*, meaning the intentionally “beaten earth” area around peasants’ huts (in Romanian *pământ bătut*=”beaten earth” referring generally to this kind of *terra trita* adjusted to the needs of human habitation not just around a peasant’s house but also within it).  Even more remarkably *bătătură* (plural *bătături*) also means literally “[callus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/callus#Noun)” (plural *calluses* or *calli*), which shows that in Romanian the verb *bate* “to beat” is understood as leading to the creation of “a hardened area of the skin (especially on the foot or hand) caused by repeated friction, wear or use”. —In fact, the formula for saying that not yet “broken in” shoes are hurting my feet and thus are producing pain, abrasion of the skin and calluses is *mă bat pantofii*, “my shoes are *beating* me”.

Not only that, but a *bătătură*=”callus” can be sometimes referred to as a “*călcâi*”, a “heel”, for saying that a such hardened area of skin has developed in an unexpected place, for example on the palm of the hand as a result of manual work —and thus the semantic circle is closed!— The heel being the exemplary callus! —As if the same action of treading/"beating" (*călcare/batere*) causes parallel results in exterior (*terra trita=*bătătură**=trodden earth/path=*callis*) and in interior (*bătătură*=callus/callum=calx/heel).

I am not an expert but from the above not only the *callis* – *callum* relation, but also that between these and *calx* seems obvious to me.

Is this convincing? If not, what arguments can be brought against?

Comment: The obvious very serious formal problem is the unexplained *-k-* in *calx*, which is lacking in *callis* and *callum*. The semantic connection between the three words isn't necessarily a point in favour of a joint origin—they might have converged in appearance due to folk etymology.

Comment: @Cairnarvon - Convergence cannot be ruled out in such cases I think, but: (1) convergence is not mentioned in etymological dictionaries, although it may impact the development and thus the "etymology" and (2) *calx* is often given with unknown origin, which may give a bit more space for speculations like the above..